# Error MIL: off Spark ignition

Tags: obd-ii, p0171

I checked my OBD2 sensor and it shows on DTC that message. Along with P0171 system too lean on my Mazda 3. I put in an injen intake and that was 3 years ago. The check engine light came on 3 months after installing the new cold air intake. Any idea on what error MIL : off Spark ignition means? Is it that i need to replace the spark plugs? I mean I have an idea what it might be.

Comment: What year/engine on your Mazda? Also, what *exactly* was the first code (P-number)?

Comment: Mazda 3 2011 2.3L only code was P0171.. That's all.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a vacuum leak. Is it possible that in replacing the cold air intake, a gasket did not seat correctly or the install did not follow the correct torque sequence or values? Also check all the vacuum hoses that are attached to the intake. You can also isolate the spot by spraying carb cleaner around the intake with the engine cold but running and if there is a leak it will suck in the cleaner and effect the engine speed. In my experience a system lean code is almost always indicating a vacuum leak somewhere.

Comment: Thanks most people didn't tell me what this meant but that makes total sense. Thanks.